# get last modification date of most recent file (recursive) and add the date to the folder name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, last-modified

i have a folder with subfolders and multiple files.

- Root\Mainfolder1\Subfolder1\files
- Root\Mainfolder1\Subfolder1\Subfolder2\files
- Root\Mainfolder1\Subfolder3\files
- Root\Mainfolder2\files
- Root\Mainfolder2\Subfolder1\files

and the batchfile is inside the rootdir

i need to get the last modification date (yyyymmdd) for the most recent file throughout all folders. 
after getting the date, i need to add the date to the mainfolders name like:
"Mainfolder (yyyymmdd)"

after that i need the same for the next mainfolder. basically i would end up with something like this:

```
Root\Mainfolder1 (yyyymmdd)
Root\Mainfolder2 (yyyymmdd)
Root\Mainfolder3 (yyyymmdd)
```

additional info: my system has another date format: dd.mm.yyyy (but i need the above format)

i want this to be a batchfile which i can place inside the root dir and then execute it to do what i have explained above. 
what code do i have so far? well near to nothing at all. nothing usable. only thing i found was how to list all modification dates (but they are not sorted or anything) with this:

```
dir /s /O:D /T:W /A:-D
```

and i cant find anything through the search function
any suggestions are highly welcomed, thanks :)

Comment: It is nice that you explained what you wanted the output to look like but sometimes you need to show a picture of what the input is as well.  If you would have said find the newest file in this folder structure `Root\Mainfolder1\subfolder1\subfolder2` it would have been more clear to me.

Comment: you are totally right. i am very sorry for not giving a good example of the input. your given example is correct. Root\Mainfolder1\Subfolder1\Subfolder2\files etc., 
the level in which the files are can vary from folder to folder

Comment: I guess you mean `/O:D` instead of `/O`, right? Anyway, `dir /S` sorts, but every sub-directory individually, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. I put some comments in the code to help you understand what is going on.  Remove the `ECHO` in front of the `RENAME` command when you are satisfied with the output.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM List the directories first
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /ad /b') DO (
    rem Change to the directory
    pushd "%%G"
    set "dt="
    set "newest="
    REM Get the date and time from the newest file from the folder.
    FOR /F "delims=" %%H IN ('dir /S /a-d /b 2^>nul') DO (
        REM by default the ~t modifier uses modified date and time
        SET "dt=%%~tH"
        REM Now split up the date into a usable format.
        REM Change the delims option to the separator your date format uses.
        REM also need a space because the time follows the date 
        FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/. " %%I IN ("!dt!") DO (
            set "dt=%%K%%J%%I"
        )
        IF NOT DEFINED newest IF defined dt set "newest=!dt!" 
        IF DEFINED newest IF defined dt IF !dt! GTR !newest! set "newest=!dt!" 
    )
    POPD
    IF DEFINED newest echo rename "%%~G" "%%G(!newest!)"
)
```

Comment: Squashman, thanks a lot. it is very close to what i need. only issue is that it does not check the files recursive. it only looks for files within the Mainfolder, but not subfolders aswell. Root\Mainfolder1\Subfolder1\file etc., how can i change the code to look for all files through subfolders within the mainfolders aswell? actually i found it myself. need to add /s here "('dir /s /a-d /b /od') DO ("

Comment: @tartaro The /S will not help in this instance.  When using the /S option it will list each directory in dated order.  It will not list the entire tree in dated order.

Comment: @tartaro, you will have to grab the date from each file and compare it to the previous to see if it is newer.  The only way to do that is to put the date in yyyymmdd order.

Comment: after your edit the appended date has now changed to (hh:mmdd.mm.yyyy), before your edit the format was already correct. the only issue i have is, that if the mainfolder contains subfolders, the files within the subfolders are not taken into account right now. the batch only works on the files that are directly within the mainfolder, but not its subfolders. do you have a solution for that please, thanks so far

Comment: @tartaro StackOverFlow is not a code writing service.  I have already gone further than anyone else would have.  Most of the time a post like yours would be closed.  I have given you the base code and told you what you need to do from here to change it.  In regards to your date being different READ the comments I put in the CODE!  I have to test with the delimiter my DATE format uses!

Comment: i cant tell where and how to add code to look through the subfolders? yes i thank you from the bottom of my heart. really. but i really try to add a little effort. i did by adding the /S function, as i thought it looks through subfolders. what else can i do?

Comment: @tartaro I updated the code to your specifications now.  I hope you take the time to read the code and COMMENTS to understand how it works.

Comment: i do take the time. thanks again. it looks through the subfolders and sorts all files this time to get the most recent. the output is also shown correct, but when i delete echo, the folders are not renamed, "the system can not find the file" it says

Comment: @tartaro, sorry,  the `POPD` needs to be before the rename.  Move it before the `IF DEFINED` for the rename.  I lost track of that when I was redoing the code.

Comment: awesome. works aswell now. this solution is even faster in processing then the one provided by Aacini. dont know the reason for that. thanks to boths solutions

Comment: This code have a potential problem: the folders are processed by a plain `FOR /D %%G` command, so if the new name of a folder is placed after the original list of folders, such a folder may be renamed twice...

Comment: @Aacini, your right.  I forgot about that.  I always knew it did that with files but was not thinking about folders.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all folders in current dir
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:D') do (

   rem Get the dates of all files in this folder and keep the most recent one
   cd "%%a"
   set "recent=0"
   for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/. " %%d in ('dir /S /T:W /A:-D ^| findstr "^..\."') do (
      if %%f%%e%%d gtr !recent! set "recent=%%f%%e%%d"
   )

   rem Rename this folder
   cd ..
   ECHO ren "%%a" "%%a (!recent!)"

)
```

If the output looks correct, remove the `ECHO` part in last line.

Comment: thank you very much. i tried this on some folders and the outcome is always "Foldername (99999999)", its really all filled with 9's, not the actual date

Comment: At the command-line, check that the output of `dir /T:W /A:-D | findstr "^../"` correctly show a listing of files, starting with the date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format.

Comment: Then do the same with `dir /T:W /A:-D` and copy-paste here a line with file data enclosed in code-marks!

Comment: Simple question: are you date parts separated by slash, like in `DD/MM/YYYY`? Or by any other character? Which one?

Comment: 17.03.2017 20:56 <- this is how dos shows the date.
also i cant list anything with that command besides the batchfile itself. therefore i cant copy anything here. i will edit my first question post so you can see my folderstructure

Comment: Add the point after the slash in `delims=/ "` part. I already did it in the above code...

Comment: @tartaro, this is the same thing I tried to explain to you in my code.  You need to use the period for the delimiter.  I even commented on it in my code.

Comment: @Aacini, I tested your code and it will rename a folder with no files in it of course to 99999999.  Also yours seems to be getting the oldest file.  Do they not want the most recent, meaning newest file.

Comment: Ops! "most recent" = "oldest file". I fixed the code with this detail... Please, copy it again!

Comment: i took the edited code and it gives me a "folder (0)" this time. i think this code does not look recursive for files?

Comment: Please, copy the code again one more time... (there were a couple small changes)

Comment: @Aacini, now I get the same output as mine.  Getting the date out if the DIR command simplifies the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch file that determines the lastest last modification date throughout a given directory tree; it depends on the local date format settings, unfortunately:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~1" & rem // (take the first command line argument as the root dir.)
rem // Define sub-string portions of the local date format -- see `date /T`:
set "_Y=0,4" & rem // (year: zero-based start char. index, length in number of chars.)
set "_M=5,2" & rem // (month:zero-based start char. index, length in number of chars.)
set "_D=8,2" & rem // (day:  zero-based start char. index, length in number of chars.)

rem // Ensure `_ROOT` not to be empty:
if not defined _ROOT set "_ROOT=."

set "LAST=00000000"
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%D in ('echo "%_ROOT%"^& dir /B /S /A:D "%_ROOT%" 2^> nul') do (
    call :GETLAST FILE "%%~D" && (
        call :GETDATE FILE "%%FILE%%"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if !LAST! LSS !FILE! (
            endlocal
            call set "LAST=%%FILE%%"
        ) else (
            endlocal
        )
    )
)

rem // Return resulting last modification date within entire directory tree:
echo(%LAST%

endlocal
exit /B


:GETLAST  rtn_path  val_dir
    ::Get last modified file in the given directory.
    ::PARAMETERS:
    ::  rtn_path    variable to receive path to last modified file;
    ::  val_dir     directory path to search last modified file in;
    ::ERRORLEVEL:   1 if no file has been found, and 0 otherwise;
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "#RTN=%~1"
    set "ITEM=%~2"
    (for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D /T:W /O:-D "%ITEM%\*.*" 2^> nul') do (
        set "ITEM=%ITEM%\%%F"
        (call ) & goto :QUIT
    )) || set "ITEM="
    :QUIT
    endlocal & set "%#RTN%=%ITEM%"
    exit /B


:GETDATE  rtn_date  val_path
    ::Get last modification date of file/dir., properly formatted like `YYYYMMDD`.
    ::PARAMETERS:
    ::  rtn_date    variable to receive formatted date;
    ::  val_path    path to get last modification date of;
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "#RTN=%~1"
    set "ITEM=%~t2"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "ITEM=!ITEM:~%_Y%!!ITEM:~%_M%!!ITEM:~%_D%!"
    endlocal & endlocal & set "%#RTN%=%ITEM%"
    exit /B
```